# How to check space being used in a table INCLUDING ghost records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I found this script somewhere else on StackOverflow which tells me the stats regarding how much space is being used by a given table:

```
SELECT 
 t.NAME AS TableName,
 i.name AS indexName,
 SUM(p.rows) AS RowCounts,
 SUM(a.total_pages) AS TotalPages, 
 SUM(a.used_pages) AS UsedPages, 
 SUM(a.data_pages) AS DataPages,
 (SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS TotalSpaceMB, 
 (SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS UsedSpaceMB, 
 (SUM(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS DataSpaceMB
FROM 
 sys.tables t
INNER JOIN  
 sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
 sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
 sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
 t.NAME = 'StmALog' AND
 i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND  
 i.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY 
 t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name 
ORDER BY 
 OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id)
```

This seems to be working well and giving me good results, however I'm not sure if these stats are also taking into account ghost records.

Could someone please verify for me that this script is counting the space used by a table *including* whatever ghost records may be hanging around?

Answer (score 0):

It is not mention in the documentations but there are [reports](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3a27a8f0-467c-4c8a-86fe-3bb1b0103bdf/no-rows-but-high-number-of-used-pages-huh?forum=sqldatabaseengine) of people wondering why the `sys.allocation_units` returns data for tables, when a huge delete/truncate is perform meaning the system view returns the `ghost records` as well.

Anyway, I do not believe you should worry to much for ghost records if ghost cleanup is enabled (it is enabled by default). Also, it is not recommended to [disable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/ghost-record-cleanup-process-guide?view=sql-server-2017#disable-the-ghost-cleanup) it:

> Disabling the ghost cleanup process is not generally recommended.
>   Doing so should be tested thoroughly in a controlled environment
>   before being implemented permanently in a production environment.

You can check the ghost records count for particular table using the following query:

```
SELECT [ghost_record_count]
      ,[version_ghost_record_count]
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats] (DB_ID(N'dabase_name'), OBJECT_ID(N'schema_name.table_name'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED');
GO
```

So, having the above query we can try to test, if your query returns ghost records as well.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [ID]  BIGINT IDENTITY(100000, 1) PRIMARY KEY
   ,[text] NVARCHAR(MAX)
   ,[date] DATETIME2 CONSTRAINT DF_StackOverflow_date DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME())
);


INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([text])
SELECT TOP 100000
           REPLICATE(CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 255)
FROM master..spt_values t1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2;

EXEC sp_spaceused '[dbo].[StackOverflow]';

-- your script for detecting size

GO

DBCC TRACEOFF(661); -- disable ghost cleaner; DO NOT RUN ON PRODUCTION DATABASE


DELETE FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];

SELECT [ghost_record_count]
      ,[version_ghost_record_count]
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats] (DB_ID(N'StackOverflow'), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.StackOverflow'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED');

EXEC sp_spaceused '[dbo].[StackOverflow]'

-- your script for detecting size

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[StackOverflow];
-- GO
```

So, after disabling the ghost cleaner, we can see that the tables has no rows, but have ghost data/rows:

[image]

Enabling the flag back, the ghost reads are cleaned:

```
DBCC TRACEON(661);

SELECT [ghost_record_count]
      ,[version_ghost_record_count]
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats] (DB_ID(N'smModel_20180828_gk7'), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.StackOverflow'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED');

EXEC sp_spaceused '[dbo].[StackOverflow]';
```

[image]

**If you want to test do not disable the flag on production database and you might need to increase the inserted rows.**